# Elastic Beanstalk platform hook no longer running

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, django-migrations

I am hosting a site via elastic beanstalk and I have a 01_migrate.sh file in `.platform/hooks/postdeploy` in order to migrate model changes to a postgres database on Amazon RDS:

```
#!/bin/sh
source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate
python /var/app/current/manage.py migrate --noinput
python /var/app/current/manage.py createsu
python /var/app/current/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

This used to work well bu now when I check the hooks log, although it appears to find the file there is no output to suggest that the migrate command has been ran

i.e. previously I would get the following even if no new migrations:

```
2022/03/29 05:12:56.530728 [INFO] Running command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_migrate.sh
2022/03/29 05:13:11.872676 [INFO] Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, home, se_balance, sessions, sites, socialaccount, taggit, users, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
Found another file with the destination path 'favicon.ico'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

Whereas now I just get

```
2022/05/23 08:47:49.602719 [INFO] Running command .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_migrate.sh
Found another file with the destination path 'favicon.ico'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.
```

I dont know what has occurred to make this change. Of potential relevance is that eb deploy stopped being ablke to find the 01_migrate.sh file so I had to move the folder and its contents .platform/hooks/postdeploy/01_migrate.sh up a to the parent directory and then it became able to find it again.

Comment: So what folder are they in now? I’d suggest moving them back where they were and editing the question to solve your first original problem.

Comment: Thanks @ErmiyaEskandary. In the top level folder exists .aws, .ebextension .elasticbeanstalk .config and mywebsite folders. Originally the .platform folder was within the mywebsite folder but when it was not able to be found I moved it up into the top level folder, it could then be found but the migrate command no longer appears to run

Comment: Note that exceptionally for prebuild & predeploy hooks, the current working directory is not the root directory. It’s the application staging directory so you probably  need to modify your current script.

Comment: However, that said, the fact that it ‘can’t be ran’, probably means an executable permission issue. Try running `chmod +x 01_migrate.sh`, the folder move may have modified some permissions on the executable.

Comment: (run this locally to grant executable permissions to the script before you package your deployment & push the zip)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary This worked (fixing the permissions) - if you want to add an answer I can give you the bounty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) on platform hooks:

> **All files must have execute permission.** **Use chmod +x** to set execute permission on your hook files. For all Amazon Linux 2 based platforms versions that were released on or after April 29, 2022, Elastic Beanstalk automatically grants execute permissions to all of the platform hook scripts. In this case you don't have to manually grant execute permissions.

The permissions on your script may have changed after moving the file around locally.

Try setting executable permissions again on your script - `chmod +x 01_migrate.sh` - and redeploying your application.