# Adding container commands to elastic beanstalk breaks deployment

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django web app hosted via elastic beanstalk

Due to the fact that ./platform/hooks/postdeploy migrate command seems to no longer bee working ([Django migrations no longer running on aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345803/django-migrations-no-longer-running-on-aws)) I have tried to use container commands in my django.config file instead

```
container_commands:
  00_test_output:
    command: "echo 'testing.....'"
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
```

This, however, provokes the error on deployment:

```
2022-05-25 08:03:36    WARN    LoadBalancer awseb-e-g-AWSEBLoa-Q8MLS7VPZA00 could not be found.
2022-05-25 08:03:36    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

This error occurs even if only the `00_test_output` command is included. Does anyone have an idea as to why the loadbalancer cannot be found when container commands are added?

Comment: This error does not seem to be caused by your code, as your code does not change or modify any load balancers. Its source must be something else.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, yes I am trying to work out what that something else might be

Comment: Did you check in EC2 console if `awseb-e-g-AWSEBLoa-Q8MLS7VPZA00` actually exist?

Comment: Yes @Marcin it exists and is active. COuld it be that the wron region is being searched. It exists in us-west-2 and this is named as my default region in .elasticbeanstalk/config.yml and.aws/config

Comment: COuld be wrong region. Difficult to speculate. You would have to provide all details of your EB setup.